# Using embedded font in StyleSheet

Tags: css, actionscript-3, stylesheet, embedded-fonts

I'm trying to use the font I've embedded in TextField.htmlText text. I've used a piece of code found here to check the font names of the embedded fonts:

```
var fonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts();
for (var i:int = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) 
{
var font:Font = (fonts[i] as Font)
trace(font.fontName, ",", font.fontStyle, ",", font.fontType)
}
```

I've used the output fontName ('Trebuchet MS') in my StyleSheet:

```
_linkStyling = new StyleSheet();
_linkStyling.parseCSS('a { color: #' + _colourScheme.link.toString(16) + '; }'); // _colourScheme returns various uint colours
_linkStyling.parseCSS('a:hover { color: #' + _colourScheme.linkOver.toString(16) + '; }');
_linkStyling.parseCSS('p { font-family: "Trebuchet MS"; }');
_linkStyling.parseCSS('p { font-size: 16px; }');
```

but that makes no difference. The text being set to the TextField.htmlText property is in 'p' tags.
The font-size styling also has no effect.
It can't be because the .parseCSSs are on separate lines because the 'a:hover' styling works. Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your two `p` selectors because you are overwriting your first definition with the second (the one containing the size).

This works:

`_linkStyling.parseCSS('p { font-size: 16px; font-family: "Trebuchet MS";}');`

Comment: Sorry - it doesn't work for me. If that was the problem the font would be 16px and (as I should have said) it's 12. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Sorry this didn't help. I copied your code and applied it to a text field that I created, and once I combined the two lines regarding the `p` selector, it worked. I'll update my answer if I have any better ideas.

Comment: Gah! I figured it out. It was the ORDER that I was setting the htmlText and styleSheet properties. Turns out you have to set the styleSheet BEFORE setting the htmlText. So your answer was right - I was just screwing it up in some other, additional way. Thanks again.